# Dashed lines in a table using arydshln

Tags: tables, arydshln, addlines

I'm trying to implement dashed lines in a table using arydshln. However, the command doesn't seem to work properly, as the dashed lines aren't drawn from top to bottom, i.e. at the top it looks a bit creepy. Anyone aware why this might not work properly (or if maybe a clash with another package is happening?). Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
%\usepackage{setspace}
%\onehalfspacing
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {figures/} }
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em} 
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{-0.8em}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addspace}
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}

\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[p]\centering
\caption{Mean value of policies}
\begin{tabular}{lccc:cccc:cccccc}
\hline\hline
                    &         Mar20 &         Apr20&         Mai20&         Jun20&        Jul20&         Aug20&        Sep20&         Oct20&         Nov20&         Dec20&         Jan21&         Feb21\\
\hline\hline
C1 school              &          14&          26&          21&          13&          10&          10&           6&           4&           5&           6&           8&           5\\
C2 work                &           4&          13&           4&           0&           0&           0&           0&           1&           2&           1&           3&           2\\
C3 public events       &          14&          26&          25&          19&          16&          15&          15&          13&          14&          15&          16&          14\\
C4 gatherings          &           6&          16&          14&           7&           5&           6&           6&           7&           9&          11&          12&          12\\
C5 public transport    &           2&           7&           5&           3&           2&           1&           0&           0&           0&           0&           1&           1\\
C6 stay at home        &           5&          16&          12&           6&           4&           5&           5&           5&           7&           8&           9&           9\\
C7 internal movement   &           5&          16&          12&           5&           4&           4&           4&           3&           4&           5&           6&           4\\
\midrule
E1 income support      &           1&           3&           3&           4&           4&           4&           3&           4&           4&           4&           4&           3\\
E2 debt relief         &           3&          11&          14&          14&          14&          14&          14&          14&          12&          12&          11&          10\\
E3 fiscal stimulus     &         631&         933&         143&          33&          11&          28&          16&          37&           8&          81&           7&           6\\
\midrule
H1 info                &          22&          28&          30&          29&          29&          29&          28&          29&          28&          29&          29&          27\\
H2 testing             &           1&           3&           6&           8&           8&           8&           8&           8&           8&           8&           9&           9\\
H3 contact tracing     &          10&          13&          16&          18&          19&          20&          19&          19&          19&          19&          18&          16\\
H6 facial covering     &           0&           4&          10&          12&          14&          15&          17&          18&          19&          21&          21&          20\\
H7 vaccination         &           0&           0&           0&           0&           0&           0&           0&           0&           0&           1&           8&          10\\
\midrule
I1 government response &          31&          62&          61&          56&          53&          53&          52&          51&          52&          54&          55&          55\\
I2 stringency          &          41&          78&          72&          61&          56&          56&          53&          51&          53&          55&          58&          57\\
I3 containment / health&          33&          64&          62&          56&          53&          53&          52&          51&          53&          54&          57&          57\\
I4 economic support    &          13&          46&          52&          54&          54&          54&          54&          52&          50&          49&          46&          44\\
\hline\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site.

Answer (score 3):

That seems to be an incompatibility between `arydshln` and `\hline\hline`.

As a workaround, we can use `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` which provides the ability to draw easily the dashed rules by using `[tikz=dashed]` as option to the specifier `|` of the vertical rules (version ≥ 6.24).

With the key `first-row`, the vertical rules won't be drawn in the first row.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em} 
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[p]\centering
\caption{Mean value of policies}
\begin{NiceTabular}{lccc|[tikz=dashed]cccc|[tikz=dashed]ccccc}[first-row]
\hline\hline
                    &         Mar20 &         Apr20&         Mai20&         Jun20&        Jul20&         Aug20&        Sep20&         Oct20&         Nov20&         Dec20&         Jan21&         Feb21\\
\hline\hline
C1 school              &          14&          26&          21&          13&          10&          10&           6&           4&           5&           6&           8&           5\\
C2 work                &           4&          13&           4&           0&           0&           0&           0&           1&           2&           1&           3&           2\\
C3 public events       &          14&          26&          25&          19&          16&          15&          15&          13&          14&          15&          16&          14\\
C4 gatherings          &           6&          16&          14&           7&           5&           6&           6&           7&           9&          11&          12&          12\\
C5 public transport    &           2&           7&           5&           3&           2&           1&           0&           0&           0&           0&           1&           1\\
C6 stay at home        &           5&          16&          12&           6&           4&           5&           5&           5&           7&           8&           9&           9\\
C7 internal movement   &           5&          16&          12&           5&           4&           4&           4&           3&           4&           5&           6&           4\\
\midrule
E1 income support      &           1&           3&           3&           4&           4&           4&           3&           4&           4&           4&           4&           3\\
E2 debt relief         &           3&          11&          14&          14&          14&          14&          14&          14&          12&          12&          11&          10\\
E3 fiscal stimulus     &         631&         933&         143&          33&          11&          28&          16&          37&           8&          81&           7&           6\\
\midrule
H1 info                &          22&          28&          30&          29&          29&          29&          28&          29&          28&          29&          29&          27\\
H2 testing             &           1&           3&           6&           8&           8&           8&           8&           8&           8&           8&           9&           9\\
H3 contact tracing     &          10&          13&          16&          18&          19&          20&          19&          19&          19&          19&          18&          16\\
H6 facial covering     &           0&           4&          10&          12&          14&          15&          17&          18&          19&          21&          21&          20\\
H7 vaccination         &           0&           0&           0&           0&           0&           0&           0&           0&           0&           1&           8&          10\\
\midrule
I1 government response &          31&          62&          61&          56&          53&          53&          52&          51&          52&          54&          55&          55\\
I2 stringency          &          41&          78&          72&          61&          56&          56&          53&          51&          53&          55&          58&          57\\
I3 containment / health&          33&          64&          62&          56&          53&          53&          52&          51&          53&          54&          57&          57\\
I4 economic support    &          13&          46&          52&          54&          54&          54&          54&          52&          50&          49&          46&          44\\
\hline\hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

It would also have been possible to define a new column type `;` with the standard command `\newcolumntype` (for legibility):

`\newcolumntype{;}{|[tikz=dashed]}`

Comment: Thank you, that looks much better. However, when I compile your code, I get no  dashed lines and 5 error messages of the type "Package pgf Error: No shape named `5' is known."

Comment: Your TeX installation is probably not up-to-date. If you use Overleaf, you should upload in your Overleaf project the latest version of the file `nicematrix.sty`. You can find that file on the SVN server of TeXLive: `https:www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty`

Comment: Great, I do use Overleaf and it worked perfectly! Thank you!!!

Comment: @Patrick Please accept this answer if it suits with you by clicking the tick mark

Answer (score 1):

- It is not entirely clear, what is your problem? That dashed vertical lines are not present in the first table row and incomplete in the second row?
- However, I wonder, why you use mix of `booktabs` rules and double `\hline`s.
- Typographically is much nicer (and professional) if instead of two `\hline`s are used `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` accordingly.
- You may consider to use `tabularray` package for writing table. By using it the table's code is far more more consistent and dashed lines are drawn from top to bottom of table:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2.5cm]{geometry}

% no arydshln package, it is not needed for this table
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}[p]
    \centering
\caption{Mean value of policies}
    \sisetup{table-format=2.0}
\begin{tblr}{vline{2,5,9}={dashed},
             colspec = {@{}
                        l *{3}{X[c, si={table-format=3.0}]}
                          *{4}{X[c, si]}
                          *{5}{X[c, si]}
                        @{}},
             row{1}  = guard
             }
    \toprule
                    &    Mar20  &    Apr20  &    Mai20  &    Jun20  &    Jul20  &    Aug20  &    Sep20  &    Oct20
                    &    Nov20  &    Dec20  &    Jan21  &    Feb21              \\
    \midrule
C1 school           &   14      &   26      &   21      &   13      &   10      &   10      &   6       &   4
                    &   5       &   6       &   8       &   5                   \\
C2 work             &   4       &   13      &   4       &   0       &   0       &   0       &   0       &   1
                    &   2       &   1       &   3       &   2                   \\
C3 public events    &   14      &   26      &   25      &   19      &   16      &   15      &   15      &   13
                    &   14      &   15      &   16      &   14                  \\
C4 gatherings       &   6       &   16      &   14      &   7       &   5       &   6       &   6       &   7
                    &   9       &   11      &   12      &   12                  \\
C5 public transport &   2       &   7       &   5       &   3       &   2       &   1       &   0       &   0
                    &   0       &   0       &   1       &   1                   \\
C6 stay at home     &   5       &   16      &   12      &   6       &   4       &   5       &   5       &   5
                    &   7       &   8       &   9       &   9                   \\
C7 internal movement    &   5   &   16      &   12      &   5       &   4       &   4       &   4       &   3
                    &   4       &   5       &   6       &   4                   \\
    \midrule
E1 income support   &   1       &   3       &   3       &   4       &   4       &   4       &   3       &   4
                    &   4       &   4       &   4       &   3                   \\
E2 debt relief      &   3       &   11      &   14      &   14      &   14      &   14      &   14      &   14
                    &   12      &   12      &   11      &   10                  \\
E3 fiscal stimulus  &   631     &   933     &   143     &   33      &   11      &   28      &   16      &   37
                    &           8   &   81  &   7       &   6                   \\
    \midrule
H1 info             &   22      &   28      &   30      &   29      &   29      &   29      &   28      &   29
                    &   28      &   29      &   29      &   27                  \\
H2 testing          &   1       &   3       &   6       &   8       &   8       &   8       &   8       &   8
                    &   8       &   8       &   9       &   9                   \\
H3 contact tracing  &   10      &   13      &   16      &   18      &   19      &   20      &   19      &   19
                    &   19      &   19      &   18      &   16                  \\
H6 facial covering  &   0       &   4       &   10      &   12      &   14      &   15      &   17      &   18
                    &   19      &   21      &   21      &   20                  \\
H7 vaccination      &   0       &   0       &   0       &   0       &   0       &   0       &   0       &   0
                    &   0       &   1       &   8       &   10                  \\
    \midrule
I1 government response  &   31  &   62      &   61      &   56      &   53      &   53      &   52      &   51
                    &   52      &   54      &   55      &   55                  \\
I2 stringency       &   41      &   78      &   72      &   61      &   56      &   56      &   53      &   51
                    &   53      &   55      &   58      &   57                  \\
I3 containment / health &   33  &   64      &   62      &   56      &   53      &   53      &   52      &   51
                    &   53      &   54      &   57      &   57                  \\
I4 economic support &   13      &   46      &   52      &   54      &   54      &   54      &   54      &   52
                    &   50      &   49      &   46      &   44                  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

and detail from upper left corner of table:

[image]

- If for some (unknown) reason you persist to have double lines in table, than this is with `tabularray` packae easy to obtain:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}


\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}[p]
    \centering
\caption{Mean value of policies}
    \sisetup{table-format=2.0}
\begin{tblr}{hline{1,2,Z} = {1}{-}{},
             hline{1,2,Z} = {2}{-}{},
             vline{2,5,9}={dashed},
             colspec = {@{}
                        l *{3}{X[c, si={table-format=3.0}]}
                          *{4}{X[c, si]}
                          *{5}{X[c, si]}
                        @{}},
             row{1}  = guard
             }
                    &    Mar20  &    Apr20  &    Mai20  &    Jun20  &    Jul20  &    Aug20  &    Sep20  &    Oct20
                    &    Nov20  &    Dec20  &    Jan21  &    Feb21              \\
C1 school           &   14      &   26      &   21      &   13      &   10      &   10      &   6       &   4
                    &   5       &   6       &   8       &   5                   \\
C2 work             &   4       &   13      &   4       &   0       &   0       &   0       &   0       &   1
                    &   2       &   1       &   3       &   2                   \\
C3 public events    &   14      &   26      &   25      &   19      &   16      &   15      &   15      &   13
                    &   14      &   15      &   16      &   14                  \\
C4 gatherings       &   6       &   16      &   14      &   7       &   5       &   6       &   6       &   7
                    &   9       &   11      &   12      &   12                  \\
C5 public transport &   2       &   7       &   5       &   3       &   2       &   1       &   0       &   0
                    &   0       &   0       &   1       &   1                   \\
C6 stay at home     &   5       &   16      &   12      &   6       &   4       &   5       &   5       &   5
                    &   7       &   8       &   9       &   9                   \\
C7 internal movement    &   5   &   16      &   12      &   5       &   4       &   4       &   4       &   3
                    &   4       &   5       &   6       &   4                   \\
    \midrule
E1 income support   &   1       &   3       &   3       &   4       &   4       &   4       &   3       &   4
                    &   4       &   4       &   4       &   3                   \\
E2 debt relief      &   3       &   11      &   14      &   14      &   14      &   14      &   14      &   14
                    &   12      &   12      &   11      &   10                  \\
E3 fiscal stimulus  &   631     &   933     &   143     &   33      &   11      &   28      &   16      &   37
                    &           8   &   81  &   7       &   6                   \\
    \midrule
H1 info             &   22      &   28      &   30      &   29      &   29      &   29      &   28      &   29
                    &   28      &   29      &   29      &   27                  \\
H2 testing          &   1       &   3       &   6       &   8       &   8       &   8       &   8       &   8
                    &   8       &   8       &   9       &   9                   \\
H3 contact tracing  &   10      &   13      &   16      &   18      &   19      &   20      &   19      &   19
                    &   19      &   19      &   18      &   16                  \\
H6 facial covering  &   0       &   4       &   10      &   12      &   14      &   15      &   17      &   18
                    &   19      &   21      &   21      &   20                  \\
H7 vaccination      &   0       &   0       &   0       &   0       &   0       &   0       &   0       &   0
                    &   0       &   1       &   8       &   10                  \\
    \midrule
I1 government response  &   31  &   62      &   61      &   56      &   53      &   53      &   52      &   51
                    &   52      &   54      &   55      &   55                  \\
I2 stringency       &   41      &   78      &   72      &   61      &   56      &   56      &   53      &   51
                    &   53      &   55      &   58      &   57                  \\
I3 containment / health &   33  &   64      &   62      &   56      &   53      &   53      &   52      &   51
                    &   53      &   54      &   57      &   57                  \\
I4 economic support &   13      &   46      &   52      &   54      &   54      &   54      &   54      &   52
                    &   50      &   49      &   46      &   44                  \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]